# A valid query syntax for OrientDB returns no results (without errors)

Tags: orientdb

My question in short - I want to search for vertices from a specific type with 2 conditions in the where-clause. when I search with each condition separately, I get results, but when I combine them with an "and" operator - I get no results and no errors.

More Details:

- I am using OrientDb 2.2.13.
- I have a vertex type called "EN182" with 2 text fields:
  "EP11" - string.
  "EP12" - emmbedded list of strings.
- I added a record to the orientDB from this type (EN182) with the values:
  "EP11" = "**Second Text**".
  "EP12" = ["First Text" , "**Second Text**" , "Third Text"]
- I get my record When I run:
  SELECT * FROM EN182 WHERE EP11 IN ['forth text','second text']
- I get my record When I run:
  SELECT * FROM EN182 WHERE ['forth text','second text'] IN EP12
- BUT when I run a query with both conditions using "AND" operator 
  **I GET NO RESULTS AND NO ERRORS**:
  SELECT * FROM EN182 WHERE EP11 IN ['forth text','second text']
  AND ['forth text','second text'] IN EP12

(It is not happening with all types, just STRING types [single & multiple value])

WHAT CAN IT BE?? 
I probably have a syntax error, but what can it be?? each condition works fine alone or with other conditions.

P.S. The index on those fields are:

- CREATE INDEX EN182.EP11 on EN182 (EP11 COLLATE CI) NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX METADATA {ignoreNullValues: false};
- CREATE INDEX EN182.EP12 on EN182 (EP12 COLLATE CI) NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX METADATA {ignoreNullValues: false};

Comment: I think the issue is the operator "IN" but how can I perform this otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

ok i tried your case and work fine (but right now i can only test it with an older version), **IF** you are reporting exactly your queries and data then is correct that your last query result is empty, because Orient is case sensitive and you have inserted a record with "EP11" = "**S**econd Text". "EP12" = ["**F**irst Text" , "**S**econd Text" , "**T**hird Text"]
but then you are searching for:
EP11 IN ['**f**orth text','second text'] AND ['**f**orth text','**s**econd text'] IN EP12
hope is only that your problem, happen more often than you think, cheers.
btw my test (index created with studio)

```
create class EN182 extens V
create property EN182.EP1 string
create property EN182.EP12 EMBEDDEDLIST
insert into EN182 (EP11,EP12) values ("Second Text",["First Text" , "Second Text" , "Third Text"])
SELECT * FROM EN182 WHERE EP11 IN ['forth text','Second Text'] and ["First Text","Second Text"] IN EP12 //return your vertex see the right codition in the filter
```

Comment: No! You missed my point - Each condition works fine and I get my (only) vertex from type EN182. when I use them both using "AND" - I get no results... (1st condition is regarding EP11 and the other - EP12, so they are not crossing each other).

Comment: (BTW- EP12 is not just embeddedList, it should be from type String. BTW2 - in the indexes you can see "COLLATE CI" which pointing the Case Insensitive, and again - it DOES WORK with each condition alone!)

Comment: ok, let me check again, maybe I have an idea of what is going on.

Comment: Please do... I feel like it has something to do with the syntax of the "IN"

Comment: Hi... sorry to buther you, but - Any luck?